# CSS is not recognized in aspx file

Tags: html, css, asp.net, path

I am trying to convert the website that I currently have in HTML/CSS/JS to aspx file. I have opened an *ASP.NET Web Application* project and I have managed to convert the HTML file to aspx but it doesn't read the CSS and JS file and the images. The head code of my project is:

```
<head runat="server">
        <title>NasaDemo</title>
        
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "../packages/styling.css" />      


        <script src="animate_news.js"></script>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </head>
```

I have saved the styling.css in the package folder together with all my images.

The File path of my Index is: C:\Users\X\Desktop\HTMl\WorkProject\WorkProject\index.aspx

The File path of my CSS is: C:\Users\X\Desktop\HTMl\WorkProject\packages\styling.css

Does anybody know what could be wrong?
Thank you very much.

[image: Browser Counsel Output]

Comment: My guess is that the package folder is outside the root of the IIS website path. Place the packages folder in the same path as the index.aspx. Then reference `href="/packages/styling.css"`

Comment: @VDWWD Hi and thank you. It worked now.